# Querying Web API With Key?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been tasked with querying a webservice API to get info for an application, and have an authentication key that I will be using. I don't know very much at all about `NSULConnections` and what not, so I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction for learning about how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), then you don't have to know much about NSURLConnection.  It has a method to globally set authentication parameters for requests.

Comment: Could you give a little more direction? I dont really know much networking at all so even pointing to a helpful tutorial would be a big help. Thanks!

Comment: Just read through the "How to Use" page there:  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: I can only seem to find info on username/password authentication, whereas mine is a simple key (looks like:"uf8FE9FhduEfjwr67r9dQfo").

Comment: It's probably a key you have to pass up as a parameter to the web service you are using.  You'll have to ask them what the parameter name is, and use the ASI docs to see how to pass a parameter to a URL request.